# Updating a Git Submodule With Local Changes

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a Git Submodule on one of my project and I'm trying to update it on my local copy where I have made some changes. I want the remote to override my local changes, but when I tried the following command, nothing happens and I still see my local changes in place.

```
joesan@joesan-S-14-v5:~/Projects/Private/github-docs/joesan-me/themes/hugo-clarity$ git status
HEAD detached at d5800ff
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   exampleSite/config/_default/params.toml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
joesan@joesan-S-14-v5:~/Projects/Private/github-docs/joesan-me/themes/hugo-clarity$
```

What is that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `git status` means *inspect and report*, so of course it did not *change* anything. Use `git restore` as it suggests if you want to undo the one file, or `git reset --hard` to undo everything very destructively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @torek comment says, `git status` is **only show you the current status of your git repo**. It will not do anything.

You can't simply use `git reset --hard` when you at super repo root. You should `cd` into submodule before `reset`, `checkout` or `restore`.

So:

```
cd path/to/submodule
git reset --hard  # or git restore .
```

if there are many submodule or you don't want to `cd` into it, you can use:

```
git submodule foreach git reset --hard
```

but this will effect all submodule under super repo, be aware!